# How do I delete a variable within the program itself

Tags: java, multithreading

Im creating an application that has multithreaded classes to count to a user specified number. Im making it so that every time the class is initiated the user specified number is passed to the constructor.

This means that the threads can only be run once since the instantiation of the class is based on the user specified number.

I would like to know if it's possible to delete the instance of the class when it has finished counting and then create another one with the same name.

Comment: Can you show us your code so far?

Comment: You didn't say why you want your instance deleted. Can you explain your problem a little better?

Comment: Not very clear without showing your code or more details. If the class contains the thread (i.e., is a Runnable), it is possible to just re-run it (provided that it's coded in a way such that multiple executions are independent, e.g., is stateless or can be reset to an initial state).

If you are trying to re-use thread (Runnable) classes without having to re-instantiate threads, then look at the thread pool facilities (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/pools.html).

Comment: Think that you mess up initiated and instantiated, that's not the same things.

Comment: I'm afraid that this question is incomprehensible.  1) "multithreaded class" makes no sense.  2) Classes are not initiated.  They are either initialized, or they are instantiated ... and these mean different things.  3) Threads can only ever be run once.  4) Creating another class with the same name doesn't make any sense.  5) Creating another instance of instance of a class with the same name only makes sense if you've implemented a mechanism for naming the instances.  And that interpretation doesn't make sense in the context of the question.  6) Deleting a variable doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just finally mark class `reference as null` once you are done. so it will automatically be eligible for `Garbage Collection`

Comment: You should clarify that ALL references to that particular instance need to be marked null for it become eligible for garbage collection.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `TimerService` and schedule it again with new user provided number. There is also `ScheduledExecutorService` also you can invoke a `Runnable`, `Callable`, `Thread` after your counter is finished.

**For Better Help Please update the Question :)**

Answer (score 0):

You can't really delete anything in Java exactly when you want to since it is the garbage collectors job to do that.

Instead, I suggest adding a reset method to your class and calling it when you are ready to reset the count. Of course you need to make sure this method is synchronized, or the data you want to reset is synchronized.